# How to save a Text property using Clojure and appengine-magic

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, clojure, google-cloud-datastore, appengine-magic

The `body` field of a form may contain long text, so the default String property won't do.

Looking for how to make the datastore use Text (this is not part of the entity definition like I recall from the Python version), I found this in the source of the ackbar blog:

```
(ns <snip>
  (:import (com.google.appengine.api.datastore
            EntityNotFoundException Text)))
<snip>
(ds/save! (Post. url title (Text. body) ts in-feed? category))
```

But if I do the same, I get: "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text"

(One notable difference is that the ackbar I'm looking at uses appengine-magic 0.3.2.)

I also tried `as-text` as briefly mentioned on https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic#readme, but `(as-text body)` in there leads to the same error message as above.

---

EDIT: Turned out the problem wasn't actually to get a Text property into the store, but to make sense of it when retrieving it. My Submit handler triggers saving and than a reload of the form page, and I failed to think of that. Sorry for the noise.

The way to get the value out without hiccup is `(.getValue body)`.

Comment: My idea is that you post a real stack trace. The exception strongly suggests that you're passing the Text object to some clojure function that expects a seq, but without an actual stack trace and with no idea how GAE works, I've no idea where to look.

Comment: How are you using the function? I tried `(ds/save! (Article. "foo" "bar" (ds/as-text "baz") 1 2))` which seems to work ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the appengine-magic documentation:

> as-text: casts a string to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text.

So you should pass a `java.lang.String` to `as-text`.

```
(as-text body)
```

Comment: That's what I meant when I said I also tried ds/as-text and it does lead to "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text"

Comment: I confirmed with `type` that `body` is a `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't quite understand your post at first. Would you mind posting your actual code? Because the example given above should work (if my eyes aren't broken).